# Atualização de DIV

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Olá, estou com um pequeno projeto apenas por Hobbie, e tenho alguns DataTables em minha página Web, para facilitar a pesquisa de dados cadastrados, mas quando eu cadastrar qualquer dado em uma aba do Brownser, no outro não aparece ao menos que eu dê um refresh/reload/f5 na página, como eu faria para automatizar esse "refresh"?

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab7">                    
<div class="content-box-large">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">Área de Serviço</div>
        <div class="panel-options">
            <a href="#" data-rel="collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body panel-refresh" id="refresh4">
        <div class="refresh-data">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example4">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Código</th>
                        <th>Área de Serviço</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $consultar_area_servico = "SELECT * FROM `$tabela_area_servico`";
                        $resultado_consultar_area_servico = mysql_query($consultar_area_servico);
                        $quantidade_resultado_area_servico = mysql_num_rows($resultado_consultar_area_servico);
                        for($i = 0;$i < $quantidade_resultado_area_servico; $i++)
                        {
                            $vetor_area_servico = mysql_fetch_array($resultado_consultar_area_servico);
                    ?>
                    <tr class="gradeA">                                         
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalAS<?php echo $vetor_area_servico['codigo'];?>"><?php echo $vetor_area_servico['codigo']; ?></button></td>
                        <td><input class="form-control"   type="text" name="c_area_servico" value="<?php echo $vetor_area_servico['area_servico']; ?>"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModalAS<?php echo $vetor_area_servico['codigo'];?>" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <form action="web/acoes.php" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="confirma" value="8">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="c_cod" value="<?php echo $vetor_area_servico['codigo'];?>">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">#<?php echo $vetor_area_servico['codigo'];?></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p>Área de Serviço:<input class="form-control"  type="text" name="c_area_servico" value="<?php echo $vetor_area_servico['area_servico']; ?>"></p>
                                        <center>
                                            <button type="submit" name="button" value="1" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Excluir</button>
                                            <button type="submit" name="button" value="2" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Alterar</button>
                                        </center>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Atualizar apenas a div ou a pagina toda ?

Comment: O mysql é obsoleto nas versões recentes do php, use mysqli.

Comment: Uma solução melhor que um refresh(ainda que bem mais trabalhosa) é fazer um pedido ajax de X em X tempo e alterar a página com base no que recebe nesse pedido

Comment: Queria atualizar todas as divs que possuam um DataTable, mas infelizmente não vai dar pra fugir do Ajax ;-;

Comment: Tem que fazer um Ajax, como vc mesmo colou nas tags.

Answer (score -1):

Se você está com duas abas abertas pro mesmo sistema e fez um insert em uma delas. Você não consegue controlar a outra aba aberta, apenas a que está com foco. 
O que poderia fazer se este foi o caso é colocar um autorefresh de tempos em tempos na sua pagina. Ou talvez eu não tenha entendido corretamente a sua pergunta.
Se for o caso do autorefresh é só inserir no seu javascript da página que deseja dar o refresh o código abaixo.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload();
}, 5000); //vai atualizar a página de 5 em 5 segundos
```

Comment: Evandir, você entendeu errado. O funcionamento que ele precisa é semelhante ao que encontramos aqui no site, quando recebemos um voto positivo por exemplo ganhamos +10 pontos e ficamos sabendo disso sem mesmo precisar dar um refresh na página.